# How to set RTL in a menu?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-menu

In my application I want use menu into navigationDrawer.
I want set RTL menu and I write below codes but not set RTL.

**My codes in menu :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl">

    <group
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:gravity="end">

        <!-- Recommended icon color code: #828282 -->
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_home"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/site_menu_home" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_menus"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu1"
            android:title="@string/site_menu_menus" />
```

**Drawer codes into XML :**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />
```

My codes result is : https://s9.postimg.org/5m000kf3z/Capture_2018-03-25-11-30-57.png

How can I fix it and set RTL menu?

Comment: Can you share `manifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `supportsRtl` in `manifest.xml`

```
<application
    ....
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    ....
>

</application>
```

And there is not need to set `layout_gravity` and `gravity` in **menu.xml**

---

If you don't want to use `supportsRtl`, you can go with custom layout for menu items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:title="Home"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/item_nav_bar" <!-- important part -->
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

**item_nav_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navImage"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        ....

        // Changing image in NavigationDrawer

        // First Item
        MenuItem item1 = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0);
        ImageView img = ((ImageView) item1.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.navImage));
    }
}
```

Remove `layoutDirection`, `gravities` from your code.

Check this [tutorial](https://stablekernel.com/using-custom-views-as-menu-items/)

Comment: Yes when add this line into manifest show Rtl. but when device language is Persian/Arabic set rtl all layouts! I don't want set RTL all layouts

Comment: How can I fix it? can you help me?

Comment: In that case, you've go with custom layout. Check my updated answer.

Comment: what is code : ="@layout/item_nav_bar" can you send to me this code?

Comment: can you help me my friend? really I need your help